# How can I create a softlayer public image via the api?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I would like to automate the following ui process:

1. Devices->Manage->Images
2. Select image
3. Actions->Create Public Image
4. Fill out fields, select all locations
5. Click Create

Can this be done via the api? Can you point me to some documentation detailing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a public image by api you can use the following rest api:

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/[imageId]/createPublicArchiveTransaction
```

Body: Json

```
{
  "parameters": [
      "groupName",
      "summary",
      "note",
        [
          {
            "id": 265592
          },
          {
            "id": 1555995
          }
        ]
  ]
}
```

Reference:
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/createPublicArchiveTransaction/

To get the private [images](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups/) Ids available in your account use this rest example:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getPrivateBlockDeviceTemplateGroups
```

To get the [location](https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/getStorageLocations/) ids available for the image use the following rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest_Block_Device_Template_Group/[imageId]/getStorageLocations
```

Or you can use this other rest example to get the locations:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Location/getDatacenters
```